# Extracting the 'text' field from a JSON tweet element and adding it to string array python

Tags: python, arrays, json, twitter, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection full of tweets that I have collected and now I would like to perform sentiment analysis on them but I only want to perform this analysis on the 'text' field of each element. I had initially had a piece of code to determine whether or not the element had a text field so ive altered it to try to detect whether it has the text field and if so to add it to the next element of the array however I get a Type Error shown below.

```
appleSentimentText[record] = record.get('text')
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict.
```

I know this means that its to do with [record] not being an integer but im confused as to how I am to make it into an integer? Im new to Python so any help would be much appreciated. Here is my snippet of code below for reference.

```
appleSentimentText = []
 for record in db.Apple.find():
  if record.get('text'):
    appleSentimentText[record] = record.get('text')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists require their indexes to be integer, hence the error.
If you want to add to the list, use `list.append` or `list.insert` methods.

```
appleSentimentText.append(record.get("text"))
```

[List methods](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: It works! Thanks so much had been riddling my brain for days with that!